# dynamic polymorphism

Tags: java

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a = new Dog();
        Dog d = new Dog();

        d.makeNoise();  // output "Sub"
        a.makeNoise();  // output "Sub"  then what is use of calling this. why not call d.makeNoise() only.

    }
}

abstract class Animal {
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Super");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Sub");
    }
}
```

We had 15 minutes discussion over this topic(15 minutes is too long I guess) I explained interviewer about how dynamic polymorphism will be achieved with the help of `a.makeNoise();`  but still she was saying both are giving same output. 
`a.makeNoise();` output "Sub" then what is use of calling this. why not call d.makeNoise() only
I went to interface also but still question was if subclass reference is giving same output then why to use superclass reference.

> Interviewer question was, what difference `a.makeNoise();` makes? why not call `d.makeNoise();` only when both are giving same output?

What could be the possible correct answer?

Comment: The possible correct answer to what question?

Comment: what is the question exactly ?

Comment: The answer appears to be that you don't understand polymorphism!

Comment: `a.makeNoise();`  // output "Sub"  then what is use of calling this. why not call d.makeNoise() only.

Comment: i think u initialize both class object animal and dog  with the same Dog class.so it will print only "sub"

Comment: @Bhavik Kama My question is not what it prints.

Comment: " but still she was saying both are giving same output. " this is what u said in your question.and i replied that way..and also polymorphism is when class sharing the same methods (actions) but implement them differently but here you calling same method of dog class with different class object

Comment: Earlier this question was closed. People have reopened this question and closing again. Why so, and people who opened this question are not answering/commenting anything. Is there any better answer can anybody give except following answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
Animal a = new Dog();    // this animal is a dog
Dog d = new Dog();       // this dog is a dog
```

A dog is a dog, however you declared it.

`a.getClass()` equals `d.getClass()` equals `Dog.class`.

On the other hand:

```java
Animal a = new Animal(); // this animal is an animal
a.makeNoise();           // prints "Super"
```

Comment: I answer the same but interviewer was expecting something else. What was it?

Answer (score 2):

The example below illustrates dynamic polymorphism. Both a and d are declared to be Animals, but d is actually a dog.

Notice that when I call makeNoise on the Animal d, java will know that d is actually a dog and not just any animal.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a = new Animal();
        Animal d = new Dog();

        d.makeNoise();  // output "Bark"  - d is an animal that barks
        a.makeNoise();  // output "Squawk"  - a is an animal that squawks

    }
}

class Animal {
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Squawk");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Bark");
    }
}
```

Comment: I answer the same but interviewer was expecting something else. What was it?

Comment: This is not the same as your answer. Look carefully at the declaration of a and d. My example will actually give different output.

Comment: I understood. But I am saying I made changes the way u changed the code and explain the whole thing, but she was expecting something else. I already noticed you changed `Animal a = new Animal();`

Comment: The important change is **Animal** d = new Dog(). Notice that `d` is an `Animal`, but when I call `d.makeNoise()` it barks. Basic animals squawk. `d`is an animal, but it barks! So when I call makeNoise() on an animal that is of a subclass it will call the method of the subclass.

Comment: I already know this, but interviewer was keep asking question, what difference a.makeNoise(); makes? why not call d.makeNoise(); only when both are giving same output? was she confuesed with her own known answer?

Comment: The difference is that `a` is declared to be a basic `Animal`. If this was a language without dynamic polymorphism than `a.makeNoise()` would make a Squawk. But since java has dynamic polymorphism, java knows that `a` is actually a `Dog` and calls `Dog.makeNoise()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason-

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

Animal is dog so noise would be same :)

If create another animal, say Cat, with that method, and point animal to Cat, you should get a different noise.

Comment: I answer the same but interviewer was expecting something else.

Comment: May be you should have attempted with an interface. Else interviewer must be expecting the method to be abstract in Animal class.

Comment: I went to interface also but still question was if subclass reference is giving same output then why to use superclass reference

Comment: Super class reference applies to all animals. Could be dog, cat, etc. At runtime, it can decide who's making the noise ;)

Comment: I answer the same but interviewer was expecting something else. What was it?

Answer (score 1):

Your simplified example does not present the case well enough.

```
Collection<Animal> caged = getCagedAnimals();
for (Animal a : caged)
  a.makeNoise();
```

As there are many types of animals (classes), each makes a different noise. We do not need any typecasting to obtain different behavior, so to say. Imagine the horrors which would happen if we would want each animal to make a noise without polymorphism:

```
for (Animal a : caged) {
  if (a instanceof Dog)
    ((Dog)a).woof(); // or, ((Dog)a).makeNoise()
  else if (a instanceof Cat)
    ((Cat)a).meow(); // or, ((Cat)a).makeNoise()
  else {...}
}
```

Let us have an object of type T. We are trying to invoke toString() (defined by Object class)
Dynamic method invocation proceeds as follows (actually, a virtual method table is used):

```
C = T
do
  if (C defines toString()) {
    call T.toString()
    break
  }
  C = superclass of C
while (C != null)
throw new NoSuchMethodError();
```

Now, if we have

```
Object obj = new T();
```

and we call

```
obj.toString();
```

we are actually calling toString() of class T.

Comment: I explained this example also but interviewer was expecting something else. What was it?

Answer (score 1):

consider there are 3 classes

1. animal
2. dog
3. cat
   cat and dog are sub classes of animal.

---

```js
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a = new Animal();
       
    int user_input=userinput();  //returns 1 for cat and 2for dog
    switch(user_input)
    {
    case 1:Animal d=new Cat();
    break;
    case 2: Animal d=new Dog();
    break;
    }
        d.makeNoise();  // output "Bark"/"meow"  as per user input(dynamic linking)
        a.makeNoise();  // output "Squawk"  - a is an animal that squawks
    }
    } 
    class Animal {
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Squawk");
    }
    } 
    class Cat extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("meow");
    }
    }
    class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Bark");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Account {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a = new Dog();
        Dog d = new Dog();
        d.makeNoise();
        a.makeNoise();
        a = new Cat();
        a.makeNoise();
    }
}

abstract class Animal {
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Super");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Sub");
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {

}
```

See the above modified example and the observations

1. We have an abstract class Animal with an implementation for makeNoise (let me say default implementation here)
2. We have a Dog class which is of Type animal but has a customized makeNoise methods
3. We have a  Cat Class which is of Type animal but has no customized makeNoise methods. it uses default makeNoise of Animal type.
4. if I use Animal a = new Dog() and a.makeNoise(),  then I can remove my makenoise method from Dog class whenever I wish with no changes to any other class.  It will still compile and execute without any error.
5. if I use Dog d = new Dog() and d.makeNoise(),  then I cannot remove my makenoise method from Dog class whenever I wish. if I do, I also need to change the main class for the application to compile.

Comment: @AmitG  I see that you edited the above answer, but no comments on whether this was useful or not

Answer (score 0):

i will give one general ex:- personA has one bank account he has all permissions on that account(withdraw,deposit,loanetc). personB wants to deposit money into personA account in this time he wants to access personA's account but we have to provide deposit permissions only.

```
 class perosnB
{
 public void deposit()
{ 
................
 } 
 } 
class personA extends personB
{  
public void deposit()
{
......
}
public void withdraw() 
{ 
...... 
} 
} 
personA p=new personB(); 
PersonB p2=new personB();
```

by using p object we can access only withdraw method. by using p2 we can access deposit  also. 
weather personA class is abstract or not. if personA is abstract class creating object for personA class is not possible( personA p=new personA()) .  personA p=new personB() is possible.

Comment: You may like to edit your answer. `personA p=new personB();` compile time error. I got your thought over this question. I answered this concept also(only concept with different example).

Answer (score 0):

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

a is a a reference of type **Animal** but it refers to the object of type **Dog**.

Here **Dog** overrides **makeNoise()** method of **Animal** class.

```
class Animal {
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Squawk");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Bark");
    }
}
```

Since object is of **Dog** class JVM will bind **Dog** class' **makeNoise()** method to the object and binding will be done at runtime.

so the Output of

```
a.makeNoise();
```

will be

**sub**